# SelectList 4 signatures vs 9, oh dear

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlist

Ref:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx

I have a VS Solution that contains the following ASP.NET MVC projects:

- Company.Domain
- Company.WebUI
- Company.UnitTests

Under Company.Domain I put my models, modules and abstract classes.  I have one module where I generate and return a `SelectList` object.  This `SelectList` object takes several parameters of which one is GROUP.  If I move this class to my Company.WebUI project (which is a ASP.NET MVC 5 web app) and I hover my mouse over the `SelectList` keyword I see it accepts **9 signatures**.  However, if I hover my mouse over the same keyword in my Company.Domain (a class based project) I see only **4 possible signatures**.

`SelectList` requires `System.Web.MVC` which is imported into the class.

Weird problem.
**How can I fix this under Company.Domain?**

Edit:
This is the line it's failing on, it's complaining `"Overload resolution failed because no accessible NEW accepts this number of arguments."`

```
AddToCache(aKey, New SelectList(GetListFromDB(SQL), "Value", "Text", "Group", Nothing, Nothing))
```

**ANSWERED**:
The question was answered by **@BilalFazlani**.  Domain was running `System.Web.Mvc` version 4.0 and WebUI running 5.2.2. Updated Domain and now all works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the version of MVC you have referenced in Domain project and compare it with MVC version of WebUI.

The **[newer version of MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx)** has more overloads of SelectList compared to the **[older version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.100).aspx)**

Comment: Why not return SelectList, it what my DropDownListFor expects. It works fine in the mvc 5 project. The only oddity is the number of signatures, don't know why it's different.

Comment: SelectListItem doesn't contain a GROUP property, only TEXT and VALUE, so it wouldn't work.

Comment: Check the version of MVC you have referenced in Domain project and compare it with MVC version of WebUI

Comment: That was it. WebUI was running System.Web.Mvc version 5.2.2 and Domain 4.0. Updated it and now all working.

Comment: Glad I was able to help. If your query is resolved, please mark as answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sure. You first have to submit it as an answer and not a comment.